# How to set state with a setInterval() when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm trying to update the count of activeIndex within the setInterval when the checkbox is ticked. handleNext() and handlePrevious() are working fine when buttons are clicked but when the checkbox is checked the value of activeIndex is not getting updated in handleNext() but it's getting updated on the screen, so there is no condition check for activeIndex and it goes beyond 3.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
    
export default function App() {
    const [slideTimer, setSlideTimer] = useState(null);
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    const slideDuration = 1000;
    
    const handleNext = () => {
        if ((activeIndex) >= 3) {
            setActiveIndex(0);
        } else {
            setActiveIndex(prev => prev + 1);
        }
    };
    
    const handlePrev = () => {
        if (activeIndex <= 0) {
            setActiveIndex(3);
        } else {
            setActiveIndex((prev) => prev - 1);
        }
    };
    
    const toggleSlider = () => {
        if (slideTimer) {
            clearInterval(slideTimer);
            setSlideTimer(null);
            return;
        }

        setSlideTimer(setInterval(handleNext, slideDuration));
    };
    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>{activeIndex}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => handleNext()}>Next</button>
            <button onClick={() => handlePrev()}>Previous</button>
            <input onClick={() => toggleSlider()} type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I have tried putting the code for toggleSlider inside useEffect() but that too is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when `handleNext` gets defined (which occurs on every rerender), it only knows about the variables/state in its surrounding scope at the time that it's defined. As a result, when you queue an interval with:

```js
setInterval(handleNext, slideDuration)
```

You will be executing the `handleNext` function that only knows about the component's state at that time. When your component eventually rerenders and sets a new value for `activeIndex`, your interval will still be exeucting the "old" `handleNext` function defined in the previous render that doesn't know about the newly updated state. One option to resolve this issue is to make the `hanldeNext` function not rely on state obtained from its outer scope, but instead, use the state setter function to get the current value:

```js
const handleNext = () => {
  setActiveIndex(currIndex => (currIndex  + 1) % 4);
};
```

Above I've used `%` to cycle the index back to `0`, but you very well can also use your if-statement, where you `return 0` if `currIndex >= 3`, or `return currIndex + 1` in your `else`.

I would also recommend that you remove the `slideTimer`. This state value isn't being used to describe your UI (you can see that as you're not using `slideTimer` within your returned JSX). In this case, you're better off using a ref to store your interval id:

```js
const slideTimerRef = useRef(0); // instead of the `slideTimer` state
...
clearInterval(slideTimerRef.current);
slideTimerRef.current = null;
...
slideTimerRef.current = setInterval(handleNext, slideDuration);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining Nick, I think I'm still confused on `executing the "old" handleNext function defined in the previous render...` any references to learn more on the same is highly appreciated ....

Comment: Hi @KcH - [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) covers the concept of "stale state" caused by a function ["closing over"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) the variables in its surrounding scope.

Comment: When I say "old" `handleNext` function I mean that each time `App` rerenders, it creates a new reference to `handleNext` that only knows about the state for that render. However, a new interval to execute that new function is not created on each rerender, but rather, the interval from the previous render is still running (which is executing the old `handleNext`, which only knows about the old state values)

Comment: makes sense Nick, so the reference to handleNext is always the one which was passed and so the values it is referring to ... did I understand it right  ... Thanks alot for sharing the article will refer it ...

Comment: @KcH No worries :) Yeah, the interval will always be executing the `handleNext` function that was passed to `setInterval()`. Even after `activeIndex` state has updated and a new `handeNext` function is defined on the rerender, the interval will still be executing the old `handleNext` function (which is referring to old state values) that `setInterval()` was originally called with

Comment: Makes sense mate, now I see why "closures" understanding is very important and esp in react 